# If $a,b,c$ are in an A.P., and $b,c,d$ are in an H.P., show that $a,\dfrac{c^2}{d},c$ is in H.P. and $b,\dfrac{ad}{b},d$ is also in H.P.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c$ are in an Arithmetical Progression, and $b,c,d$ are in an Harmonical Progression, show that $a,\dfrac{c^2}{d},c$ are in H.P. and $b,\dfrac{ad}{b},d$ are also in H.P.

Arithmetical mean: $a+c=2b$

$c=2b-a  \tag{1}$

Harmonical mean: $\dfrac{2bd}{b+d}=c$

Thus $\dfrac{2bd}{b+d}=c \Rightarrow c(b+d) = 2bd$

Using $(1)$ $\Rightarrow (2b-a)(b+d)=2bd \Rightarrow 2b^2+2bd-ab-ad = 2bd \Rightarrow 2b^2=ab+ad$

$ad=2b^2-ab \tag{2}$

We are told $\dfrac{c^2}{d}=\dfrac{2ac}{a+c} = \dfrac{ac}{b}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{a}{b} \Rightarrow ad=bc$

Using $(2)$ $\Rightarrow 2b^2-ab=bc \Rightarrow b(2b-a)=bc$

From $ (1)$ $\Rightarrow bc=bc$.

For $\dfrac{ad}{b}=\dfrac{2bd}{b+d}$

Using $(2)$ $\Rightarrow \dfrac{2b^2-ab}{b}=\dfrac{2bd}{b+d} \Rightarrow 2b-a=\dfrac{2bd}{b+d} \Rightarrow 2b^2+2bd-ab-ad=2bd \Rightarrow 2b^2-ab=ad$

Which is equivalent to $(2)$.

Althought I've solved it, the problem is I made the assumption that $\dfrac{c^2}{d}=\dfrac{2ac}{a+c}$ is true at the very *beginning* and used this fact to do my calculations, when this is something that I'm supposed to *prove*. I think my conceptual approach was wrong, but I don't know how to do the calculations otherwise.

Comment: In a sense you basically used the same principles as [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction). Suppose that the given sequence is not a harmonic progression, and then show that leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Given nonzero real numbers $\,a,b,c,d\,$ define for convenience
$$ A:=1/a,\;\;B:=1/b,\;\;C:=1/c,\;\;D:=1/d $$ and the quantities

$$ Q_1 := AB - 2AC + BC,\qquad Q_2 := B - 2C + D,\\
   Q_3 := AD - 2C^2 + CD,\;\; Q_4 := B^2 - 2AD + BD. $$

Verify that

- $\,Q_1 = 0\,$ iff $\,a,b,c\,$ are in A.P. because
  $\,abcQ_1 = c - 2b + a = a - 2b + c$
- $\,Q_2 = 0\,$ iff $\,b,c,d\,$ are in H.P. iff
  $\,B=1/b,C=1/c,D=1/d\,$ are in A.P.
- $\,Q_3 = 0\,$ iff $\,a,c^2/d,c\,$ are in H.P. because
  $\,dQ_3 = A - 2C^2/D + C$
- $\,Q_4 = 0\,$ iff $\,b,ad/b,d\,$ are in H.P. because
  $\,bQ_4 = B - 2AD/B + D$

Verify the simple algebraic identities
$$ Q_1 - (A+C)Q_2 + Q_3 = 0. $$
$$ 2Q_1 + (B-2A)Q_2 - Q_4 = 0. $$

Given $\,Q_1=Q_2=0\,$ the two identities imply $\,Q_3=Q_4=0.\,$
Thus, this answers the question

> If $a,b,c$ are in an Arithmetical Progression, and $b,c,d$ are in an Harmonical Progression, show that $a,\dfrac{c^2}{d},c$ are in H.P. and $b,\dfrac{ad}{b},d$ are also in H.P.

Comment: How did you come up with $Q_1 := B + D - 2C,\qquad Q_2 := AB + BC - 2AC,  Q_3 := AD + CD - 2C^2,\;\; Q_4 := B^2 + BD - 2AD$? Thanks.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson Oops! Thanks for that comment. I mixed up $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. Fixed now.